# R Calculate cumsum for every third value

Tags: r

I wanto to calculate the sum of every 3 values which are not `NA`.
I hope that I can explain my problem with the following example dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble( 
  date = lubridate::today() +0:19,
  value= c(1,2.5,2,NA,NA,6.5,1,9,3,8,4,7,NA,NA,NA,1,5,3,6,7))

> df
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   date       value
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2021-04-16   1  
 2 2021-04-17   2.5
 3 2021-04-18   2  
 4 2021-04-19  NA  
 5 2021-04-20  NA  
 6 2021-04-21   6.5
 7 2021-04-22   1  
 8 2021-04-23   9  
 9 2021-04-24   3  
10 2021-04-25   8  
11 2021-04-26   4  
12 2021-04-27   7  
13 2021-04-28  NA  
14 2021-04-29  NA  
15 2021-04-30  NA  
16 2021-05-01   1  
17 2021-05-02   5  
18 2021-05-03   3  
19 2021-05-04   6  
20 2021-05-05   7
```

I need first an index, which helps me to explain my request in more detail:
`df$index<-c(1,1,1,NA,NA,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,NA,NA,NA,4,4,5,5,5)`

I wanto to group every 3 rows which are not `NA`. For this purpose the `index`-column was created. Then I want to calculate the sum over the 3 grouped values in the last row of the group:

`df$cumsum<-c(NA,NA,5.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,16.5,NA,NA,15,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,13,NA,NA,16)`

My final dataframe should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
   date       value index cumsum
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2021-04-16   1       1   NA  
 2 2021-04-17   2.5     1   NA  
 3 2021-04-18   2       1    5.5
 4 2021-04-19  NA      NA   NA  
 5 2021-04-20  NA      NA   NA  
 6 2021-04-21   6.5     2   NA  
 7 2021-04-22   1       2   NA  
 8 2021-04-23   9       2   16.5
 9 2021-04-24   3       3   NA  
10 2021-04-25   8       3   NA  
11 2021-04-26   4       3   15  
12 2021-04-27   7       4   NA  
13 2021-04-28  NA      NA   NA  
14 2021-04-29  NA      NA   NA  
15 2021-04-30  NA      NA   NA  
16 2021-05-01   1       4   NA  
17 2021-05-02   5       4   13  
18 2021-05-03   3       5   NA  
19 2021-05-04   6       5   NA  
20 2021-05-05   7       5   16
```

Can someone help me with ma problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove `NA` values
- Create group of 3 rows
- Put the `sum` of `value` in the last row of each group.
- Join to the original dataframe to get all rows back.
- `arrange` the data by `date`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(index = ceiling(row_number()/3)) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = ifelse(row_number() == n(), sum(value), NA)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  right_join(df, by = c("date", "value")) %>%
  arrange(date)


#   date       value index cumsum
#   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2021-04-16   1       1   NA  
# 2 2021-04-17   2.5     1   NA  
# 3 2021-04-18   2       1    5.5
# 4 2021-04-19  NA      NA   NA  
# 5 2021-04-20  NA      NA   NA  
# 6 2021-04-21   6.5     2   NA  
# 7 2021-04-22   1       2   NA  
# 8 2021-04-23   9       2   16.5
# 9 2021-04-24   3       3   NA  
#10 2021-04-25   8       3   NA  
#11 2021-04-26   4       3   15  
#12 2021-04-27   7       4   NA  
#13 2021-04-28  NA      NA   NA  
#14 2021-04-29  NA      NA   NA  
#15 2021-04-30  NA      NA   NA  
#16 2021-05-01   1       4   NA  
#17 2021-05-02   5       4   13  
#18 2021-05-03   3       5   NA  
#19 2021-05-04   6       5   NA  
#20 2021-05-05   7       5   16
```

Comment: Is there also a solution without creating the `index` and `cumsum` column?
I want to overwrite the `value`-column directly with the new values. And maybe without the `right_join`-command?

Comment: You would need `index` column to create groups, although you can remove it with `select(-index)` at the end. You can directly replace `value` column by using `mutate(value = ` instead of `mutate(cumsum = `.  To do this without a join command we might need to think of another logic than the one I have implemented here.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Overwriting is easy. But can you offer a solution without the `join`-function?